# Scanner specifics

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am making a program to get some grades from an external file, find the sum and average of them, and display that. In addition, the program stops when it reaches zero. My question is that when I test if the next number is not zero, it skips that number and then therefore does not use that number in the calculation. My current approach to this is:

```
while ((current = inFile.nextInt()) != 0) {
            System.out.println(current);
            sum += current;
            numberOfScores++;
        }
```

setting the next int to a variable at the same time it is tested. While this way works, there surely must be an easier way to get this done. Is there?

Thanks in advance for the help
--Cheers

Comment: How are you creating the Scanner object?

Comment: `while ((current = inFile.nextInt()) != 0) {` I would recommend restricting assignment to outside a boolean condition area for sanity's sake.

Comment: So set inFile.nextInt() to a variable, test it, and then display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your prompt- are you looking to simplify your approach, or to be able to continue past the zero?

Either way, your approach here is a little risky. This begs for program crashes. I'd recommend something among these lines, where you ensure that there is another int.

```
while(inFile.hasNextInt()){
    int tmp = inFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println(tmp);
    sum += tmp;
    numberOfScores++;
}
```

If you want, you could add in some code to skip over 0s.